# Programmatically removing Exit Popup from Page?

Tags: php, javascript, html, iframe

I have a page A which has exit popup. I want it to be show on Page B. I used iframe for displaying page A on B.

Edit:Page A is having a Exit Popup which i dont want in Page 2.

But Page A is having annoying popup. Assuming i can't edit Code of Page A. Can i just make some code in my page B . To remove Exit Popup?

Please provide me with sample code. I would prefer it to run on My Lamp Shared hosting.

I can use anything in place of Iframe if need be.

Thanks.

Comment: "having annoying popup" is not descriptive enough for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: Is page A on your server? Or are you trying to serve someone else's page in a frame on your site, but without their exit popup?

Comment: No, i dont own page A. But Its free to use content of page A.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what you mean but if you want to use pop up you can  use [jQuery fancybox plugin](http://fancybox.net/)

Comment: I dont want the Exit Pop on page B. Which is on Page A